# How does a spark java program work

Tags: java, scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

I am new to spark. In hadoop mapreduce, the map function is called each time for each line of the file and setup function is called once for each mapper.

How does the spark map function work.

I have the below code of mapper and i want to implement it in spark.

```
public static class PairsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,Text> {
private String firstFilePath;
private List<String> sourceRecords;
private String line;
//Declare variables for column positions in record


        private int pos_last_name=0;

public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {    


        firstFilePath = context.getConfiguration().get("firstFilePath");
        new ArrayList<String>();
        sourceRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
        FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(firstFilePath)); 
        for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
        String line;                
        while((line= bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        sourceRecords.add(line.toString());

        }
        }
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        line = value.toString();

        String[] target = line.split(",");

        if (target.length==21){
            for(String inputLine : sourceRecords){

                    if ((!(inputLine.equals(line))) && inputLine.length() > 0 && line.length() > 0) 
                {
                    String[] source = inputLine.split(",");

                  if (source.length == 21){
                    //Blocking using String comparison of _LastName, _FirstName, Gender and _FirstName, Gender, DOB
            if (source[pos_last_name].equals(target[pos_last_name]))
                    {
                        context.write(new Text(inputLine), new Text(line));
                    }
                    }

                }
            }
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to convert your mapper to a Spark application:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.File

  val sc = new SparkContext("your_spark_master", "your_application_name")
  // Read from a local dir
  val sourceRecords = new File("your_dir_path").listFiles().flatMap(file => Source.fromFile(file).getLines.toList).filter(_.length > 0)
  val sourceRecordsBc = sc.broadcast(sourceRecords)
  val inputRDD = sc.textFile("hdfs://your_input_path")
  val outputRDD = inputRDD.filter { _.length > 0 }
    .map { line => (line, line.split(",")) }
    .filter { _._2.size == 21 }
    .flatMap {
      case (line, target) => {
        val pos_last_name = 0
        for (
          inputLine <- sourceRecordsBc.value if inputLine != line;
          val source = inputLine.split(",") if source.size == 21 && source(pos_last_name) == target(pos_last_name)
        ) yield (inputLine, line)
      }
    }
  outputRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://your_output_path")
```

This is just an example. I have not tested it yet. If you find any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Thanx a ton. i tried to run it as a program using sbt but facing some errors. but from shark-shell i ran the code line by line. its working fine.

Comment: Also please tell me. these two files I am comparing are very large. So what wud be the best practice. Should I load both the files in cache??

Comment: Maybe you do not config sbt correctly. If you find a memory issue, another option to do such thing is using the `join` operator in Spark which will be slower.